# React JSX defaultProps syntax error

Tags: reactjs, syntax-error, jsx

i try to use this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Hello extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        somename: "World!"
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello {this.props.somename}</h1>
        );
    }
}
```

But i then i try to build it in webpack i get syntax error here:

static defaultProps **=** {

I didn't use jsx and lates ECMAScript standarts before. Can somebody explain me how it must be correctly write.

**UPD:**
my webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const entryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/js');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: {
    app: entryPath + '/app.js',
    main: entryPath + '/main.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/js'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/, 
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,  
                loader: "babel-loader", 
                options: {
                    presets: ["env", "react"] 
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: how is your `.babelrc` file configured?

Comment: you need `stage-2` in your `.babelrc` config

Comment: @Icepickle UPD: add my webpack config

Comment: @mwl i use webpack, look it (upd)

Comment: Try `babelrc: false` in options. If the error is still there, kindly post the error too.

Comment: @DenisRoss .babelrc and webpack are not mutually exclusive, they are rather combined and best practise ;) (at least according to the babel website)

Comment: @Icepickle oh ,ok, thanks for your advice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did not want to play around with your `.babelrc` file, you can rewrite your code like so:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Hello extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello {this.props.somename}</h1>
        );
    }
}

Hello.defaultProps = {
    somename: "World!"
}

export default Hello
```

If this is not an option and you wish to use static class properties, then you will want to use a Babel plugin. I use [babel-plugin-transform-class-properties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties). There is a [great tutorial on the Babel website that shows you how to implement this.](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/)

From the tutorial, installation is done by:

`npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

Then add the following code to your `.babelrc`:

```json
{
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a static function do the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Hello extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello {this.props.somename}</h1>
        );
    }
}

Hello.defaultProps = {
    somename: 'World!',
}

export default Hello;
```